# Inequality for difference of powers

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I want to show that the inequality

$$2^{1-p}|x-y |^p \leq \left|\, x \vert x \vert^{p-1} - y \vert y \vert^{p-1} \,\right|$$

holds for every $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and every $p \geq 1$. I found this in my analysis paper but sadly I could not prove it. I tried to use the convexity of the function $x \mapsto \vert x \vert^p$ and also tried to use an integral representation. Can someone give me a hint or a link where this is shown? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There are basically two cases:

- $x>0>y$, in which case replace $y$ by $-y$ and rewrite the inequality as
  $$\dfrac{x^p+y^p}{2} \geq \left (\dfrac{x+y}{2} \right )^p,$$
  where $x,y>0$. This follows from the fact that the graph of $f(x)=x^p$ is concave up.
- $x>y>0$. In this case rewrite the inequality as
  $$\dfrac{x^p-y^p}{2} \geq \left (\dfrac{x-y}{2} \right )^p,$$
  but a stronger inequality holds in this case:
  $$x^p-y^p \geq (x-y)^p \geq 2(x-y)^p/2^p.$$

Comment: Can you suggest how to prove the first part of 3rd inequality?

Comment: Generally $(a+b)^p \geq a^p +b^p$ for $p\geq 1$. To prove this, for example divide by $b^p$ and reduce to $(t+1)^p \geq t^p+1$ which follows from showing that both expressions are 0 at $t=0$ but the derivative of the left hand side is greater than the derivative of the left hand side for $t>0$ and $p\geq 1$.

Comment: No the problem is $x^p -y^p \geq  (x-y)^p$, if we take $y^p$ to right hand side, we have similar form as you said but then $x-y$ can be negative

Comment: We assumed $x>y$ for that part. The case $y>x$ follows similarly.

Comment: Ah, sorry for not observing properly!